# Socket Emiting data only first time

Tags: angular, sockets, websocket, socket.io, ionic4

I am new in angular. I created an application which receives data from localhost server. But my angular component getting data from server only once. When i am opening page for the next time. It doesn't getting data. It only firing event only once. When i going to back page and coming back to my socket page then it doesn't getting value.

> private-video.ts

```
export class PrivateVideoPage {
  constructor(private webSocketservice:WebsocketService) {
  }
  
  ngOnInit()
  {
    console.log("hello")
    this.webSocketservice.listen('test event').subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log("socket data=>",data);
    })
  }
}
```

> websocket.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class WebsocketService{
    private socket;

    constructor() {
        this.socket = io('http://localhost:5000',{'multiplex': false});
     }

    listen(eventName:string)
    {
        return new Observable((subscriber)=>{
            this.socket.on(eventName,(data)=> {
                subscriber.next(data);
            });
        });
    }

    emit(eventName:string,data:any)
    {
        this.socket.emit(eventName,data);
    }
}
```

> main.js(server)

```
let app = require("express")();
let http = require("http").Server(app);
let io = require("socket.io")(http);

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log("user connected");

  socket.on("disconnect", function() {
    console.log("user disconnected");
  });

  socket.on("message", message => {
    console.log("Message Received: " + message);
    io.emit("message", { type: "new-message", text: message });
  });

  data=[{id:1,name:'ashish'},{id:2,name:'mishra1'}];
  socket.emit('test event',data);
});

http.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("started on port 5000");
});
```

Comment: I think you need to remove `data=[{id:1,name:'ashish'},{id:2,name:'mishra1'}];` line before `socket.emit` from `main.js`.

Comment: @micronyks that is my data which i want to send

Comment: you are listning only on `listen('test event')` so will recieve only `[{id:1,name:'ashish'},{id:2,name:'mishra1'}]` (once)

Comment: @bubbles yah but when i am going on previous page and coming back on my socket's page, then its not showing data. Why? and how i can solve it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> In Node index.js

```
// Init
const app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

export const socket = (update) => {
    io.sockets.emit('updates', {availability: update});
};
```

> In Angular

```
npm i ngx-socket-io
```

> In your App Module please import

```
    import {SocketIoConfig, SocketIoModule} from "ngx-socket-io";

    const config: SocketIoConfig = { url: 'http://192.168.8.164:3000', options: {} };

    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config)
```

> In your Service File

```
    constructor(private socket: Socket) {

    }

    listenSocket() {
        return this.socket
            .fromEvent<any>('updates')
            .map(data => data.availability);
    }
```

> In Your Component's onInit

```
this.particularService.listenSocket()
        .subscribe(msg => {
          //do whatever u want
        });
```